# What is the best gaming framework for android and iphone

Tags: android, iphone

What is the best gaming framework that can I use for both android and iPhone ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how there can be a 'correct' answer to this question, but I recommend Cocos2d-x as it's cross-platform for iPhone and Android.  It's 2d only, if you want a 3d game, I recommend Unity3d, but it's very expensive.

Comment: Looked at Cocos2d-x, looks pretty nice tho, seems to be for games idd, and can be build for iOS and Android, atleast, they say it can :)

Comment: It's supported by a big Chinese games company and has regular updates, so it should be around for a long time.

Comment: Btw, for a limited time (until 8th April 2012) the iPhone and android versions of unity3d are free!

Answer (score 1):

For 3D [Unity3d](http://unity3d.com) is the best. It's not expensive unless you want/need the pro version. The standard iphone/android versions are reasonably priced.

[Cocos2D](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) is awesome for iphone 2D but would need porting for android (quite a lot work doing that I reckon).

Comment: Btw, for a limited time (until 8th April 2012) the iPhone and android versions of unity3d are free!

Answer (score 0):

You can use 3rd party tools to create apps that work in both (apple and android at the same time). That's what Titanium and PhoneGap could be used for.

However, I don't know if they are any good for games. Never used those programs, I only used eclipse (android).

Answer (score 0):

The first that comes to me is Corona: http://www.anscamobile.com/corona/

**EDIT** :
You can find a lot of interesting tutorials about Corona SDK on this Website : http://mobile.tutsplus.com/category/tutorials/corona/

Comment: ShiVa 3D seems to be interesting to design 3D games cross-platform : http://www.stonetrip.com/